# What does "for" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a sentence as follows:

> For everyone who reads and applies the Bible, there will be one more of happy people in the world.

What does "for" mean? At first I think it means "because", but if so, it's nonsense in this sentence. Can you explain it?

Comment: There are many problems with your sentence; the meaning of "for" is the least of your concerns. _For_ here means roughly _" As affecting the interests or condition of."_

Answer (score 4):

When **for** combines with a word like *each*, *every*, *all*, *some* followed by a noun, it acts as an iterator of the members of the specified subset of class [noun].

In respect to each member of the subset of the class...

> For every success, the inventor had ten failures.
>
> For each of the first five chapters in the book, write a short summary of the plot.
>
> For every rabbit dispatched, an additional four heads of lettuce went to market.
>
> For every pot there was a lid.
>
> For many a student, this was the first time they had seen snow.

Answer (score 1):

The word "for" here sets up a correspondence. "For every X there is a Y" means that each X has a corresponding Y.

Answer (score 0):

The whole sentence can be rewritten as: "one more person reading and applying to Bible is one more happy person in the world" 
or 
"for each person reading and applying to Bible there is one more happy person in the world". 
So "for", or maybe more widely "for everyone" here means "for each one".